# Is this a perfect forwarding function?

Tags: c++, templates, perfect-forwarding

Is this a perfect forwarding function? Or does the creation of a temporary T make it non-perfect? T is a trivial class.

```
template<class T, typename... Args>
void foo(Args&&... args)
{
    bar(T{std::forward<Args>(args)...});
}
```

If it is a perfect forwarding function I expect it to incur no overhead, but creating a T must incur overhead unless a suitable optimisation is available to the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perfect forwarding doesn't mean no overhead, and in current C++, perfect forwarding always has the potential to create undesired temporary objects. For example:

```
class C { C(int); };

void foo(C c);

template <class Arg>
void bar(Arg&& arg) {
    foo(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
}

C getC();

int main() {
    foo(getC());
    bar(getC());
}
```

In the call `foo(getC())`, guaranteed copy elision occurs, and the return statement in `getC` constructs the `C` object directly into the parameter `c` of `foo`, with no copies or moves taking place. In the call `bar(getC())`, which uses perfect forwarding, the prvalue `getC()` is materialized first in order to be bound to the reference parameter of `bar`, and then the move constructor of `C` is called in order to initialize `c` from `std::forward<Arg>(arg)`.

You might say that perfect forwarding isn't perfect.

Anyway, what "perfect forwarding" means, then, is that lvalues are forwarded as lvalues of the same type, and rvalues are forwarded as rvalues of the same type. In your original example, lvalues passed to `foo` are forwarded as lvalues of the same type to the constructor of `T`, and rvalues passed to `foo` are forwarded as rvalues of the same type to the constructor of `T`. So yes, you have perfect forwarding here.